# Can't render style sheet on my Meteor app (MIME error)

Tags: css, meteor, less

This is the error I'm receiving when trying to load CSS/less data:

[image]

I looked around StackOverflow for the same problem and I find out that I had to use an absolute URL for the stylesheets. I tried basically every combination of the URL where my stylesheets are located, but I still get the same error but only different link attached.

The stylesheets that I need to render are located in `/client/stylesheets/less`, but no matter what URL path I type, i get the same MIME/type error.

Can anyone be kind enough to point a fellow in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the .css and .less extension are set up to use text/css as the MIME Type either on the server level or for your web application.  You can add this MIME type to your web.config if you do not have access to the server level configuration.

```
<system.webServer>      
  <staticContent>           
    <remove fileExtension=".less" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />           
  </staticContent>      
</system.webServer>
```

The remove is included for if the setting is configured at the server level already to not cause a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to install the less compiler?

```
meteor add less
```

Comment: Nope, compiler is installed.